# How can I get a new array filtered by value in another array of objects? javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, iteration

I want to get only the array of presents modify by the scoreChild, but result1 include the name also, I am finding little bit hard to understand iteration object inside array with array

```
  const wishesData = [
    {
       name: "Peter",
      presents: ["coffee", "holidays"]
    },
    {
       name: "Mario",
      presents: ["coffee", "videogames"]
    },
    {
       name: "Amanda",
      presents: ["computer", "tattoo"]
    },
    {
      name: "David",
      presents: ["car","clothes"]
    }
  ]
  const scoresData= [
    {
      name: "Peter",
      score: 10
    },
    {
      name: "Mario",
      score: 6.3
    },
    {
       name: "Amanda",
      score: 1.1
    },
     {
       name: "David",
      score: 8
    }
  ]

  const childScore = scoresData.find(s=>s.name=== "Amanda").score

  console.log("Amanda score",childScore)

const result1 = wishesData.filter((ele)=>{
 
console.log("estos childScore=>",childScore)
  if(ele.name === "Amanda"){
    if(childScore>7){
    return ele.presents
  } else if(childScore<7 || childScore>5) {
    return  [...ele.presents, "coal"]
  } else if (childScore<5){
    return ele.presents.slice(0,1).concat("coal")
  }
  }

})

console.log(result1)
```

this is the result I am expected:
result1 =  ["car","coal"], I mean each time I change the name of child I will get the array with the presents he "deserve" according to his score

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I don't know why this question has been downvoted so much, because OP explained what they're trying to do and provided their attempt. Come on guys

Comment: If you understand the question, Jeremy, I applaud it. I probably have a bad day in understanding.

Comment: I want to modify presents array according to the score the child gets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you want to have different behaviour depending on score.

For this example, you will never reach the last test in this function

```
  (ele)=>{
 
  console.log("estos childScore=>",childScore)
  if(ele.name === "Amanda"){
    if(childScore>7){
    return ele.presents
  } else if(childScore<7 || childScore>5) {
    return  [...ele.presents, "coal"]
  } else if (childScore<5){
    return ele.presents.slice(0,1).concat("coal")
  }
  }

}
```

because the part

```
else if(childScore<7 || childScore>5) {
        return  [...ele.presents, "coal"]
      }
```

will return true for everything, maybe you wanted `&&` instead of `||`

Another thing, if you want to just have the presents value, `filter` is not what you need, since it only wants a boolean value in return to create a new array with only values matching the predicate.

you can use `reduce` method here like this

```
const result1 = wishesData.reduce((acc, ele)=>{
  console.log("estos childScore=>",childScore)
  if(ele.name === "Amanda"){
    if(childScore>7){
      return ele.presents
    } else if(childScore<7 || childScore>5) {
      return  [...ele.presents, "coal"]
    } else if (childScore<5){
      return ele.presents.slice(0,1).concat("coal")
    }
  }
 return acc;
})
```

Hope this answers your question ! :)

Edit : The part inside can be simplified to

```
if(childScore>7) return ele.presents;
if (childScore<5) return ele.presents.slice(0,1).concat("coal");
return [...ele.presents, "coal"];
```

or even

```
return childScore>7 ? ele.presents : [...(childScore < 5 ? ele.presents.slice(0,1) : ele.presents), "coal"];
```

if you wanted a one-liner (note that `[ele.presents[0]]` may be more readable than `ele.presents.slice(0,1)` as well)

Comment: how can I make it more declarative? . anyway ,thank you very much.

Comment: what do you mean by 'more declarative' ? :) like more flexible to use the same thing for all children ?

Comment: I mean shorter , more readable (declarative vs imperative programming) ;)

Comment: depends on which part of the code you talk about. if it is the if / elses you want to remove to be 'more declarative', you can either find a logical way to match a number with an action, iterate over an array of functors and tests or use a switch / case (simpler but not really more declarative per se since js doesn't offer pattern matching as fp languages do for declarativeness). Here is an example for switch
```
switch (true) {
 case childScore>7:
   return ele.presents;
 case childScore<7 && childScore>5:
  return  [...ele.presents, "coal"];
 case childScore<5:
 return //
}
```

Comment: But these solutions are a bit too tricky for what you want to achieve i think, and for just three cases like that i think the simpler way is ifs (would be less obvious if you had for instance 8 different cases, in such case an array of functors with tests would have been more readable.
Also note that your else are useless since you return each time from the function.
Also you can just ignore a check because it will be the default value (ie : you can check childscore>7, the childscore < 5, and just return the value in your middle check in the end

Comment: (I just updated my answer to better explain what i think was better)